# Power of a matrix and its symmetricity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real $N\times N$ matrix. If $A^k$ is symmetric for some $k>0$, does that give away something about $A$.

Comment: If you mean in terms of symmetry than $A$ need not be symmetric if $A^k$ is for some $k\ge 2$.

Comment: may be in terms of symmetry or may be in terms of its trace or eigenvalues or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A^k$ is symmetric, it has real eigenvalues. So, at least you know that if $\lambda=re^{i\theta}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, you must have $\theta=im\pi/k$ for some integer $m$.